# Is there a way to set min_df and max_df in gensim's tfidf model?

Tags: gensim, tf-idf

I am using gensim's tdidf model like so:

```
from gensim import corpora, models

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(some_corpus)
mapped_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text)
                 for text in some_corpus]

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(mapped_corpus)
```

Now I'd like to apply thresholds to remove terms that appear too frequently (max_df) and too infrequently (min_df).  I know that scikit's CountVectorizer allows you to do this, but I can't seem to find how to set these thresholds in gensim's tfidf.  Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your dictionary with

```
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=min_df, no_above=rel_max_df)
```

Note that `no_below` expects the minimum number of documents in which tokens must appear, whereas `no_above` expects a maximum relative frequency, e.g. `0.5`. Afterwards you can then construct your corpus with the filtered dictionary. According to the [gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html) it is also possible to construct a `TfidfModel` with only a dictionary.